# Unable to present in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, presentviewcontroller

The following code works in a `UIViewController`, but in my class thats a `UITableViewCell` it's giving the error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'present'.

The code is an action:

```
@IBAction func linkAction(_ sender: Any) { 
  let linkString = self.linkText.text 
  if let requestUrl = URL(string: linkString!) {
     let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: requestUrl)
     present(safariVC, animated: true)  
  }
}
```

Is there a fix?

Comment: Please review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=present+%5Bswift%5D+uitableviewcell) for many possible solutions.

Comment: presentViewController is a method from UIViewController, not UIView

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the main UIViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idCell", for: indexPath)
  cell.viewController = self
 
}
```

In the UITableViewCell class:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  
  weak var viewController: UIViewController?

  @IBAction func linkAction(_ sender: Any) { 
    let linkString = self.linkText.text 
    if let requestUrl = URL(string: linkString!) {
       let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: requestUrl)
       viewController?.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Very slick solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to communicate back to the ViewController that presents this TableView. Either with a remote notification, or delegate.